# Minesweeper game board | ruby

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I have written a code for the drawing board for the minesweeper game, can anyone help me to refactor this code more.

Please find my code below

```
def draw(height, width, mines)
  board = Array.new(height) { Array.new(width,0) }
  x =  Random.rand(height)
  y = Random.rand(width)
  mines.times do
   until board[x][y] != 'x'
    x =  Random.rand(height)
    y = Random.rand(width)
   end
   board[x][y] = 'x'
  end

  board.each_with_index do |row, i|
   row.each_with_index do |elem, j|
    next if board[i][j] == 'x'
    count = 0
    count += 1 if i+1 < height && board[i+1][j] == 'x'
    count += 1 if j+1 < width && board[i][j+1] == 'x'
    count += 1 if i-1 >= 0 && board[i-1][j] == 'x'
    count += 1 if j-1 >= 0 && board[i][j-1] == 'x'

    board[i][j] = count
  end
end

 board.each do |row|
   row.each do |e|
     print "#{e} "
    end
  print "\n"
 end 
end

draw(4,4,3)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like it belongs on [codereview.se] instead of [so]. However, in order to be on-topic over there, you should describe in detail *what* the code is doing and the *goals* of the review should be.

Comment: Your Job #1 is to explain the problem you are trying to solve. "the Minesweeper game" is inadequate. You need to state the rules of the game and explain what your code is supposed to do. As Jörg suggested, you should move your question to Code Revew (which provides advice on improving *working code*, as opposed to SO's main reason for being: fixing broken code). To do so, flag your question for moderator attention, requesting that it be moved to Code Review. Alternatively, you can delete the question and re-post at Code Review.

Comment: I have an answer for you if you move your question to Code Review. I don't want to post it here as I think it's likely your question will be closed as being "off-topic" because you have presented working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to check 8 adjacent cells, not 4. Since this is a refactoring, I kept the original behavior.

```
def draw(height, width, mines)
  board = Array.new(height) { Array.new(width, 0) }

  mines.times do
    x = rand(height)
    y = rand(width)

    redo if board[x][y] == 'x'

    board[x][y] = 'x'

    [[x - 1, y], [x + 1, y], [x, y - 1], [x, y + 1]].each do |x, y|
      next if x < 0 || x >= height
      next if y < 0 || y >= width
      next if board[x][y] == 'x'

      board[x][y] += 1
    end
  end

  board.each { |row| puts row.join(' ') }
end
```